# Stack Exchange Facebook OpenID login issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I was trying to search for an old message in my *inbox* on Stack Overflow and clicked on `all Items` link which redirected me to [`https://stackexchange.com/users/login`](https://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2Fusers%2F4600810%3Ftab%3Dinbox) which displays the following page:

[image: Login page]

This is the first time I am trying to login/signup on Stack Exchange. I never used it before, and I currently use Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange with my Facebook login, and I wanted to use the same one here to sign-up, but as soon as I click on the OpenID option for Facebook, the `graphAPI` throws an error:

> "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

And it redirects me to the following page:

[image: Redirect page]

Is this issue occurring for everyone or is it me only, or I am trying to do it the wrong way? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: problem occurs for me only on area51 (as far as I tested)

Comment: Also [reported in SO.es](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3010/83), where removing the cookies solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem but could not solve removing the cookies (tested on area51)

Comment: same here didnt worked, even after removing cookies :( still looking to find the issue here.

Comment: Still having the problem. Did you guys solve it?

Comment: still not resolved :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that we had a typo in the callback URL. It's fixed in production now.

Sorry about the delay, and thanks for the report!